# Request rights with native Mac OS X dialog for pcap

Tags: macos, pcap

is there an easy way of requesting root rights for whole app with native dialog in Mac OS X? I am doing packet capture which requires root access to network device. I am using C++, not objective C. I need equivalent functionality of 'debug as root' in Xcode.

Thank you!

EDIT: or maybe how would one incorporate osascript into the .app which would request root access for the app?

Answer (score 5):

In Unix, a process can't elevate its own privileges. Anyway, it's a really bad idea to run a whole app with root privileges, because its attack surface will be huge. You should use a privileged helper program to do the bare minimum necessary and then exit.

See Apple's [Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Introduction.html) and particularly the article about [Elevating Privileges Safely](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html).

You can use [SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) to install your privileged helper tool.

Comment: These are all Objective C methods, no?

Comment: There's some Objective-C code in the SMJobBless sample code, but the meat of it is C API. Both `AuthorizationCreate()` and `SMJobBless()` are C functions. You can take the code within the `-blessHelperWithLabel:error:` method and transplant it to C function (and replace the `NSLog()` call) and it would still work.